# onAttach() activity parameter null?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a main activity class, and a private inner class within the main activity. The private inner class has methods that when called will display fragments. This inner class implements an interface defined in the Fragment's class, to be used as a sort of callback. It is probably easiest to show through code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

//on a button clicked
EditItemManger em = new EditItemManager();
em.begin();



private class EditItemManager implements on EditItemFragment.EditedItemClickedListener{

//consructor, other stuff. no onCreate method because this inner class does not (explicity??) extend activty

public void begin(){
EditItemFragment editItemFrag = new EditItemFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(editItemFrag, EDIT_FRAG_TAG)
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
        public void onEditItemClicked() {
            editFinish();
        }


public void editFinish()
{
 // other stuff
}

}

}
```

**My EditItemFragment class, where the onAttach method always has a null activity parameter**

```
public class EditItemFragment extends DialogFragment {
    protected EditedItemClickedListener editedItemClickedListener;
    protected ImageButton button;

    public EditItemFragment(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_name_fragment, container, false);
        button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.submit_new_item_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                        editedItemClickedListener.onEditedItemButtonClicked();
                }
            });

            @Override
            public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
                super.onAttach(activity);
                try {
                    editedItemClickedListener= (EditedItemClickedListener) activity;
                } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public interface OnEditNameButtonClickedListener {
                public void onEditNameButtonClicked();
            }
```

So because the parameter in onAttach() in my Fragment class is always null, it eventually causes a null pointer exception. I am wondering if it is because the fragment is called from a class that is not extending activity. The problem is that if this class extends activity, there will be an issue with trying to commit the Fragment Transaction

Answer (score 0):

I guest your onAttach returns nullpointer exception. Its because your parent Activity the main activity doesnt implement your custom interface so it return null. See the code below let me know if it help you:

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements EditItemFragment.EditedItemClickedListener{ 
       private DialogFragment editItemDialog;
     //Do your code here
       @Override
        public void onEditItemClicked() {
            editFinish();
        }

      public void showDialog(){
           //this is for showing your custom dialog fragment
         editItemDialog = EditItemFragment.newInstance();
         editItemDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"editItemDialog");
      }

}
```

this is for your EditItemFragment:

```
    public class EditItemFragment extends DialogFragment{
       //Do your code here

    public static EditItemFragment newInstance(){
         EditItemFragment editItemDialog = new EditItemFragment();
         return editItemDialog;
     }

}
```